# Angular LocalStorage Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, local-storage

i have passed a lot of time to get data from controller to another using Angularjs
i found this module https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage and i like it , i get object object issue [object Object] 
my first controller code

```
 $scope.getUserFunction = function () {

     $scope.username;
     $scope.password;

      $scope.data;

      //var data = {username: 'akram',password: "yes"};
      $http({
        method  : 'POST',
        url     : 'http://localhost:8080/JersyBackEnd/resources/login',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        data: 'username='+$scope.username+'&password='+$scope.password
        //headers: {username: "toto",password:"toto"},
      })
        .then(function(data) {
         // $window.location.href = "/about.html";
//          $cookieStore.put('user',data);
          localStorageService.set('users',JSON.stringify(data));

       //   console.log("Employee",x);
          $scope.data = data;
          console.log(data);


        }, function (error) {
          console.log(error)
        });

    };
```

and second controller code

```
 $scope.getEmployee = function () {
       //var cookie = $cookieStore.get('user');
      //console.log("Employee"+cookie);
     var users = JSON.parse(localStorageService.get('users'));

      console.log("happiens"+users);
    }
```

i get happiens[object Object] in console

1 . how to resolve this problem ? 
2 . is this a good idea to get data from controller to another

and thanks :)

Comment: What is stored in `users`? It's obviously an object. Try console.log(users), not console.log("happiens"+users).

Comment: For logging a string and an object separate them with a comma so they are separate parameters. `console.log("happiens", users);`  You are trying to concatenate a string and an object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log("happiness", users);
```

Or

```
console.log("happiness", JSON.stringify(users));
```

OR

```
console.log("happiness" + JSON.stringify(users));
```

One of them will work.